# Are Python primitives objects or primitves like an object

Tags: javascript, python

```
 'apple'.upper() // in javascript
```

As I know it is first wrapped as an object and value is returned and wrapper is destoryed

```
'apple'.capitalize() // in python
```

Does the same take place in python or it's just a real object.

**Edit:**
As answered they are just plain vanilla objects in python.

Now as I understand primitives are fast hence their counter Object wrappers are provided.

Then why woudn't python implement them? Is there any pariticular design reason? Pros and cons on two approaches.

Comment: No primitives in Python! Everything's an object. Some objects like strings or integers are immutable, though.

Comment: Are there any pros of it, given when other languages have wrapper why didn't python implement it. Like in javascript everything is an object, strings are immutable still 'apple'.something will go through a wrapper.

Comment: Strings are also immutable in Python...

Comment: What immutablity has to do with primitives?

Comment: why a downvote?

Comment: Side note, AFAIK the better Python analogy to `toUpperCase` is `.upper()`.

Comment: thx, updated the same. But question still remains, `javascript` is also a scripting language. In it string acts like a object but is a primitive which is to make things faster. Now what strikes me is why didn't python have it? given it doesn't cause any inconvenience for the user. There should be some tradeoffs? Probably language implementer could answer that. Comparing with `java` caused all types of confusions.

Comment: You're taking the Java idioms of "primitive" and "object" and trying to apply them to other languages and confusing yourself. "Primitive" and "object" have very precise meanings in Java's lang spec and well defined consequences for performance. In other languages, these words have less meaning (or no meaning). Just because a string is an "object" in a language, it doesn't mean it has to take up a lot of space and be slow. Java objects aren't the same as python objects. "Objects" can be optimised to be quick or be converted to "primitives". These details are internal for compiler/interpreter.

Comment: @garg10may the enormous advantage is that it simplifies the semantics of the language greatly: **everything is an object**. If you create many strings, the overhead of an object can begin to have an impact, but Python interpreters implement things like string interning to ameliorate this concern.

Comment: thx, now it makes sense. Answer should have been bcoz python implements string interning.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not Java. It does not have primitives. Nor does it wrap or unwrap objects.

`'apple'` is an object of type `str`.

Comment: wouldn't that make language slow?

Comment: Not particularly. Why would it?

Comment: Because they are heavy, why did Java take extra measures to give primitives than, or javascript make wrappers?

Comment: @garg10may Yeah, Python is probably a little slower than Java. Python is an interpreted scripting language, I don't see the problem. If everything languages did was oriented entirely at speed we'd still be programming in machine code.

Comment: Why? What's the point? Different languages make different implementation decisions. You shouldn't expect them all to be the same.